# Looking for proper way to run code when array from async function is ready

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous

I am looking for a best practice solution for my current ES6 javascript solution. I hope someone could point me in the right direction.

I am at the point, where I am fetching a bunch of posts from a paginated REST API and storing them inside an array. The fetching of posts is async and will finish some time after the DOM is ready.

Once the fetch script is complete, it will spit out an array containing the entire list of posts fetched. When the array is available, I want to loop through it.

I have seen in similar cases, that others used a timer to check each milisecond, if the array is ready. I am not sure, if that it is the correct method to implement.

What is the best practice using ES6 javascript to check if the array from the async function is ready to loop through?

The following script is what I use to fetch the posts with. I have tried to explain the code within the comments.

```
// Constant variable with the assigned value of a joined string containing the base URL structure of the REST API request. 
const apiUrl = websiteUrl + '/wp-json/wp/v2/punkt/';

// Logging out the base URL of the REST API.
console.log('REST API is this: ' + apiUrl);

// Local variable with the default value of true assigned. Variable is used to control the paginated fetch of the API.
let keepfetchingPosts = true; 

// Local variable that contains the limit of posts per request. 
let limitPerPage  = 20;

// Constant variable, which is assigned a function as the value. The function is async and will return a promise. 
// The function takes one argument. The argument holds the value of the page number. 
const getPosts = async function(pageNo = 1) {

    // Local variable assigned with the base URL string of the REST API request. Additional queries are added to the end of the string.
    let requestUrl = apiUrl + `?page=${pageNo}&per_page=${limitPerPage}`;

    // Logging out the REST API request
    console.log('URL is this: ' + requestUrl); 

    // Logging out the argument 'pageNo'
    console.log('Retreiving data from API for page : ' + pageNo);

    // Local variable assigned with a fetch function that returns a promise. The URL request are used as the function argument.  
    let apiResults = await fetch(requestUrl)

        // If request is success, then log and return the following to the local variable.
        .then(function(response){

            // Logging out the status code of the response.
            console.log('HTTP response is: ' + response.status);

            // return JSON and status code of the XHR request
            return { 
                data: response.json(),
                status: response.status
            }

        })
        // Catch the error and log it out within the console. 
        .catch(function(error){

            console.log('HTTP response is: ' + error.status)

        });


    // If the length of the request is less than the limitPerPage variable and status code is 200, then...
    if (apiResults.length < limitPerPage && apiResults.status === 200){

        // Set the boolean to false
        keepfetchingPosts = false;

        // Return the JSON of the successfull response.
        return apiResults.data;

    } else if (apiResults.status === 200) {

        // If the status code is 200, then return the JSON of the successfull response 
        return apiResults.data;

    } else {

        // Otherwise, set the boolean to false
        keepfetchingPosts = false; 

    }
    }

    // Defining a constant variable that holds and async fynction. An async functon will always return a promise. 
    // The function takes one argument, which is set to 1 by default.
    const getEntirePostList = async function(pageNo = 1) {

// Try and catch statement used to handle the errors that might occur. 
try {
        // Constant variable which is set to the return variable of the function getPost(). Get post returns the successfull paginated response of the request. 
        const results = await getPosts(pageNo);

        // Logging out a string including the length of the array.
        console.log('Current array contain ' + results.length + ' items...');

        // Conditional statement that checks if the length of the array named 'results' is less than the variable named limitPerPage. Condition is also checked, if bolean is true. 
        // If the conditions are met, the code will join the arrays into one big array.  
        if (results.length < limitPerPage && keepfetchingPosts === true) { 

            // Logging out a string that indicates an attempt to combine that last array to the existing array. 
            console.log('Combining last array!');

            // Return the combined array. 
            return results;

        } else if (keepfetchingPosts === true) { 

            // Logging out a string that indicates an attempt to combine the recent fetched array to the existing array.   
            console.log('Combining arrays!');

            // Returning the new combined array and increments the pageNo variable with 1. 
            return results.concat(await getEntirePostList(pageNo+1));

        } else { 

            // Logging out a string that indicates the script will stop fetching more posts from the REST API.  
            console.log('Stop fetching posts and return results');

            // Returning the complete array. 
            return results;

        }
    // Catch statement that takes the argument of the error that occured. 
    } catch(error) {

        // Logging out the error. 
        console.log(error);

    }

};( async () => {

    // Constant variable with the assigned value received from the function 
    const entireList = await getEntirePostList();

    // Logging out the enite list of results collected from the REST API
    console.log(entireList);

    })
();
```

The script spits out the array named 'entireList'.

Comment: "*others used a timer to check each milisecond, if the array is ready*" - that's horrible. Don't do polling.

Comment: Your code works as expected, right?

Comment: Is your code working and you want to know if that's the best way? Not quite sure I understand.

Comment: The code I posted above is working. I am looking for a suggested solution about how I check that the array is ready and I am able to loop through it within another function.